callback Vungle.onInitializeEvent is not called on UWP build
I have set up vungle ad for UWP build by Unity. The
callback Vungle.onInitializeEvent is not called after calling function Vungle.Init.
And I have tried log many other callbacks like Vungle.onLogEvent, Vungle.onErrorEvent, Vungle.onWarningEvent, Vungle.onAppTrackingEvent to check if any error is happening => then all above callbacks are not called.
